# Why will this jquery work in Firefox but not Chrome?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This code work as intended in Firefox but it does not work in Chrome or IE.
How come?

```
var controlOpa = 0;

$(window).scroll(function() {

    if(controlOpa <= 100) {

    $("#foo0").css("top", "+=10");
    $("#foo1").css("top", "+=12");
    controlOpa += .5;

    } else {

        $(window).unbind('scroll');

    }
});
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net example would be great.

Comment: Any particular part of it that doesn't work? Do you have any console errors?

Comment: What is "as intended"? What does it do in Firefox? How does it differ in other browsers? Does it do something different, or fail completely? Do you get any error messages in the console? You need to give a bit more detail.

Comment: +=10 in the css is a string

Comment: so if it is a string how would I make it work in Chrome?

Answer (score 2):

`+=10` is not a valid value for the `top` property. Do this instead:

```
var top0 = $('#foo0').css('top'),
    top1 = $('#foo1').css('top');

$('#foo0').css('top', top0 + 10);
$('#foo1').css('top', top1 + 10);
```

**Edit**: My bad, that is actually valid in jQuery 1.6 and above.

Comment: Why not simply `$('#foo0, #foo1').css('top', function(i,t) { return t + 10; });`? Though, obviously, in the question it should be `+ 12` for `#foo1`.

Comment: I wasn't trying to give the shortest answer but the one that made the problem the clearest :-)

Comment: I tried but that didn't work. The div's are set to position:relative, does that prevent it from moving in Chrome?

Comment: So you're saying the problem is with CSS and not jQuery then? You might want to update your question accordingly.

Comment: I do not know if the problem is with CSS, I'm not sure. I thought it was a jquery problem. It works fine in Firefox, so I assumed the problem was not with CSS.

Comment: I found this solution.                                           var newtop = $("#foo0").position().top + 50;
    $("#foo0").css('top', newtop + 'px'); It works in Chrome but it updates slow.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to get the top scroll offset for each div on scroll and add 10 to it when the page scrolls, here's what that would look like, in pure JS:

```
var foo = document.querySelectorAll('#foo0', '#foo1');
window.addEventListener('scroll', function(){
  foo[0].scrollTop += 10;
  foo[1].scrollTop += 12;
}, false);
```

Without an explanation of intended behavior, what your `controlOpa` variable was for, or what you intended by removing the scroll listener after 100px of scroll, I couldn't really include those things and be sure it outputs what you intended. If you let me know a bit more, I can work those things into the example.

Comment: Basically I have 20 divs on the stage taking up the entire stage. They are in width (screen width / 20) and height is set to 100%. All of the divs have different colors. I want them to animate out of the screen when user scroll the mousewheel. When the user scroll they will scroll down and at the same time all divs are animating out of view. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: It works great in firefox but for some reason Chrome and firefox does not move the divs at all. I now tried with this solution $("#foo0").position().top + 50; $("#foo0").css('top', newtop + 'px'); and it works but very very slowly.

Comment: found a solution using animate instead. This works in Chrome and firefox.  .animate({top: '+=50'}, 0);